# Printed Text in Word a lot better than in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, rgb, ppi, microsoft-word

I am porting a design that has been sent to me in Word to Photoshop.

One part of the design contains a text with the font *Bacalisties*

When I try to print the original word layout to a white paper, the quality of the printed text is far better in Word than it is in the photoshop created layout. In photoshop I can spot lack of smoothness in the letters being printed. I am printing the text in a 40pt size in a A4 document, no scaling over 100% is being done anywhere.

How can this be?

I have increased the ppi settings in Photoshop from 72 to 300, and afterwards to a whopping 3000 PPI, same result.

I am using the same printer, with the same settings, to print both documents. I have tried printing directly from the photoshop document, I have tried exporting to a PDF, I have created a photoshop document natively in RGB and the convert to CMYK to print, I have created the file natively in CMYK, I have tried merging all the layers, and everything I could think of.

How is it possible that the printed artwork is so much worse in Word?

Some additional information I left out yesterday:

When I try to create a text in Photoshop, there is an option (not sure if it's antialias) whose default value is sharp. I have tried printing with sharp and smooth and the result is the same. Highly pixelated text, totally different from what I see if the same text is printed from a Word document.

Comment: Start by describing how you do this. At the moment you offer us nothing to evaluate things by. Just saying my porche dont give me better performance than my wogswagen golf.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your comment. I tried being as descriptive as possible. I mentioned the resolution of the image, the settings, how I exported, color mode and other things. What exactly should I add @joojaa ?

Comment: Well first of all we dont know how you do the conversion. Its only the most relevant thing. PPI is a red herring  you should probably ignore that for now. But also most likely your printer does not understand cmyk either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are trying to use:

> to a whopping 3000 PPI

probably implies that you are not understanding resolution and how it is working on your process.

A two-part answer.

**I.**

The text inside Word will be resolution-independent. It will print naturally on the printer.

**II.**

> I am porting a design that has been sent to me in Word to Photoshop.

How, what... how?

You are not focusing on what are you doing to "port" a design made in Word to Ps. I am a bit ignorant here. I do not know any direct way to "port" a design.

You could export Word to PDF but this will probably process some content of the design into a raster image at low resolution.

You could make a screen capture so this will be pixelated from start.

You could copy-paste some things of the word document.

Etc.

In the end, what you are most likely doing is rasterizing the text at some point, so it looks blurry when printed.

---

Do not use Ps.

Use Illustrator, Corel Draw, Indesign, Scribus, or Affinity Design, and re-create the layout on it. But only if you really need to.

If you only need home printing or office prints, you could leave it in Word format.

You need to define your needs, then the tools, then the process to do a re-layout on a new program.

Comment: Maybe porting is not the right term here. I have received a word document with a few elements, some texts and images. I am redoing that in photoshop, so I am recreating the same elements in Photoshop. Issue: A text written in word with 'Bacalisties' font prints perfectly in word, the same text written in photoshop results in a highly pixeled image.

Comment: Creating text while in a raster editor will result in the text being converted to pixels. That's how the program works. If you create rather large text, the pixel aspect will be much less. I use Paint Shop Pro which creates vector text, but the bitmap output is raster and pixelated, especially small size lettering.

Comment: Doing this in illustrator did the trick. Thanks a lot Rafael.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.